# iOS - Build error trying to archive with Fabric (Twitter)

Tags: ios, heroku, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to archive a build so it will get sent to Fabric. I'm pretty sure Fabric is installed correctly so that's not my concern. I have been searching online but really haven't found anything. Here's the full error

```
2015-08-25 13:11:09.959 run[26550:11059125] Fabric.framework/run 1.3.16
/Users/Lee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lista-dhwaxiksyxxmbaceoefmiorzjzal/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Lista/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Lista.build/Release-iphoneos/Lista.build/Script-FF08409C1B0A90E700BFB8AD.sh:
line 3: 97f760e8cb7dfcfb21897fa3255a4f21a9b2be11b72ac6b6f94b28a3df41d165: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

Any ideas?? I'm desperate at this point.

Here's what's in that file:

```
#!/bin/sh
./Fabric.framework/run 0e8d9569f0d4e9a7da32002c77b2c04a90e56082
    97f760e8cb7dfcfb21897fa3255a4f21a9b2be11b72ac6b6f94b28a3df41d165
```

Comment: How are you trying to build it exactly, and did you read the `error`?

Comment: I'm trying to archive the build. So product->archive. Just running the build on my device works fine.

Comment: What's on `line 3` of `Script-FF08409C1B0A90E700BFB8AD.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some changes in your Fabric framework, try to remove the Run script which you have added in you Build Phases, then integrate the Fabric framework again in your project. Removing the Run script will remove this error.The add the script again so the Fabric will work in your app.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone reading this in the future trying to reinstall crashlytics, you need to go back to the main page on Fabric and hit + new app to reset it. Then you can get the build script again.